# Some cells do not have separators in static UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, interface-builder

[image]

As the picture showed above, I created a UITableView in Interface Builder. When I finished, I find that there is some separators missing. How can I make every cell 's two separators not disappearing?

Comment: Is your simulator at 100% scale? If not, they might be interpolated away ...

Comment: @TheEye Absolutely yes! I cannot believe its this problem!

Comment: Been there, done that ;-).